# Random crashes in WaitNextEvent under 10.7.2

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

Our (legacy) app runs stable on a range of OS versions (10.4 - 10.7) since years and now randomly crashes at ONE customers computers (both of them, though) within `WaitNextEvent`.

All crashes occur deep inside Apple's code with random locations but always with `WaitNextEvent` somewhere in the call stack.

Examples are:

```
            Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
            0   dyld                            0x8fe8a33d _ZN4dyldL10loadPhase5EPKcS1_RKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE + 716
            1   dyld                            0x8fe8a501 _ZN4dyldL10loadPhase4EPKcS1_RKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE + 179
            2   dyld                            0x8fe8ae31 _ZN4dyldL10loadPhase3EPKcS1_RKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE + 1429
            3   dyld                            0x8fe8b1f1 _ZN4dyldL10loadPhase1EPKcS1_RKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE + 166
            4   dyld                            0x8fe8b340 _ZN4dyldL10loadPhase0EPKcS1_RKNS_11LoadContextEPSt6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EE + 240
            5   dyld                            0x8fe8b3fd dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 132
            6   dyld                            0x8fe8e036 dlopen + 428
            7   libdyld.dylib                   0x977b9a95 dlopen + 70
            8   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x90d467cf GetDYLDEntryPointWithImage + 43
            9   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x90d50aed GetDYLDEntryPoint + 45
            10  com.apple.AppKit                0x9c62cf2c _IsCarbonFullScreenInstanceWorkspace + 57
            11  com.apple.AppKit                0x9c03231c -[NSApplication _updateFullScreenPresentationOptions] + 75
            12  com.apple.AppKit                0x9bdc97d5 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 906
            13  com.apple.AppKit                0x9c4d81e1 _appActivationHandler + 547
            14  com.apple.AppKit                0x9c4d79b8 carbonAppApplicationHandler + 108
            15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bb9f920 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
            16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba1b803 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1602
            17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba1ac80 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 482
            18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba1aa98 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 75
            19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba306fe _ZL29ToolboxEventDispatcherHandlerP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 3152
            20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba1bcbe _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 2813
            21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba1ac80 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 482
            22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ba2faa9 SendEventToEventTarget + 76
            23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bb9f76c ToolboxEventDispatcher + 82
            24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bbb1e0f GetOrPeekEvent + 482
            25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bbb217f GetNextEventMatchingMask + 539
            26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bbb24b7 WNEInternal + 434
            27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bbb1784 WaitNextEvent + 53
            28  com.ourStuff                0x000bebe5 LApplication::ProcessNextEvent() + 69
```

or

```
            Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
            0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9c2dec22 mach_msg_trap + 10
            1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9c2de1f6 mach_msg + 70
            2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98f370ea __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 170
            3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98f40214 __CFRunLoopRun + 1428
            4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98f3f8ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 332
            5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98f3f798 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 120
            6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95b7fa7f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 318
            7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95d1c151 GetNextEventMatchingMask + 493
            8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95d1c4b7 WNEInternal + 434
            9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95d1b784 WaitNextEvent + 53
            10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95cfc136 ModalDialog + 1638
            11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95d03ff5 RunStandardAlert + 741
            12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95d028bf StandardAlert + 201
            13  com.ourStuff                0x0007fbaa 0x1000 + 519082
```

**Any** hints are highly appreciated!

As of now we couldn't reproduce the bug locally.

Comment: Wow. Nice to see a fellow PowerPlanter here. :) I don't have any answer for you but I do remember some years ago one of my apps also randomly crashed inside WaitNextEvent. After days of hair-pulling, I finally pinned it down to an extra CFRelease to a CFStringRef somewhere else in my code. Some how it never crashed near the extra release but much later in the event loop.

Comment: It's a weird one! But the crashes are happening on one customer's system only - and he's got the DefaultFolderX hack installed, which shows up in every crash dump...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW - the crashes just disappeared after that particular customer deactivated **DefaultFolderX** (which kept showing up in every crash dump of our app on the customers system)..